# Mockito: как замокать параметр типа Class?

Tags: java, mockito

У меня есть тест, бегущий под Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
```

В этом тесте мне нужно замокать вот такой метод:

```
mapper.map(dto, Entity.class)
```

(это маппер).

например, вот так:

```
when(mapper.map(any(), any()).thenReturn(result);
```

Если мокать простым `(any(), any())`, работать не будет.

Как правильно описать второй параметр в моке, чтобы всё работало корректно?

Comment: Методы не мокаются, только объекты.

Comment: приведите пример метода в классе, и как и что мокаете, так не совсем понятно, в чем/где проблема

Comment: @keekkenen добавил в описание проблемы.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Почитайте документацию там все кратко и понятно (даже с гугл переводчиком).. Конструкция вида `when(..).thenReturn(..)` подразумевает что, то, что написано в when должно выполниться с теми параметрами, с которыми вызывается, но в результате выполнения вернется то, что прописано в thenReturn. Таком образом, никакие any() не могут передаваться в метод, а только объекты ожидаемых типов. Поэтому, если реальное выполнение map метода не нужно, тогда следует использовать такую конструкцию `doReturn(result).when(mapper).map(any(), any());`

Comment: @keekkenen Вы просто не поняли, что я имел в виду (хотя, для Вас я дополнил вопрос). Но ничего страшного в этом нет. Наверное, это от того, что Вы новичок здесь. Как только я найду решение, я обязательно сообщу Вам, каким оно было.

Comment: я может и новичок здесь, но решение я написал выше, но в чем сложность передать вторым параметром действительное значение и убедиться, что в конструкция в целом работает/не работает( я предполагаю второе)

Comment: Вы предположили, а я, прежде чем создавать топик, попробовал все варианты, которые нашёл в интернете, и они не работают. Спасибо за ответ, и желаю Вам поскорее набраться опыта в комментировании вопросов :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение неочевидное, но оно было найдено спустя два месяца назад.

```
when(restTemplate.getForObject(eq("http://localhost:8081/api/account"), eq(Account.class)))
.thenReturn(account);
```

Ключевых детали две.

1. Класс Class мокается только через `eq(MyClass.class)`.
2. Остальные параметры должны быть заданы тоже через `eq()`.